# Trying to create multiple data frames while web scraping in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm still pretty new to coding and especially web scraping, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I wanna scrape fbRef.com to create a data frame for some of each Premier League teams' match stats.

I know this works for getting the team links:

```
library(rvest)
page <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"
scraped_page <- read_html(page)
teamLinks <- scraped_page%>%
   html_nodes("#stats_squads_standard_for a")%>%
   html_attr("href")
teamLinks <- paste0("https://fbref.com/",teamLinks)
```

I'm also able to create a list of each team's name based on this same info

```
Team <- scraped_page%>%
   html_nodes('#stats_squads_standard_for .left')%>%
   html_text()%>%
   as.character()
```

But now I want to create a data frame for each team separately and scrape each team's page for specific stats. I have a for loop to get the stats I need, but I don't know how to separate it or how to name each data frame with the team name.

```
for (i in 1:length(teamLinks)){
  url <- teamLinks[i]
  scraped_url <- read_html(url)
  Team <- scraped_page%>%
    html_nodes('#stats_squads_standard_for .left')%>%
    html_text()%>%
    as.character()
   df_name <- paste0(Team[i])
   df <- {
    Comp <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(comp)%>%
      html_text()
    Venue <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(venue)%>%
      html_text()
    Result <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(result)%>%
      html_text()
    Goals_For <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(GF)%>%
      html_text()
    Goals_Against <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(GA)%>%
      html_text()
    Opponent <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(Opp)%>%
      html_text()
    xG <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(xg)%>%
      html_text()
    xGA <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(xga)%>%
      html_text()
    Possession <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(poss)%>%
      html_text()
    Formation <- scraped_url%>%
      html_nodes(formation)%>%
      html_text()
    data.frame(Comp,Venue,Goals_For,Goals_Against,
               Opponent,xG,xGA,Possession,Formation)
  }
}
```

also any help cleaning up that for loop would be much appreciated

these are the values for each html variable as well:

```
comp <- ".left:nth-child(3) a"
venue <- ".left:nth-child(6)"
result <- "#matchlogs_for .left+ .center"
GF <- "#matchlogs_for .right:nth-child(8)"
GA <- "#matchlogs_for .right:nth-child(9)"
Opp <- ".left:nth-child(10)"
xg <- "#matchlogs_for td.left+ .right"
xga <- "#matchlogs_for .right:nth-child(12)"
poss <- "#matchlogs_for td:nth-child(13)"
formation <- ".left:nth-child(16)"
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list before the loop and save each dataframe into that list, as in:

```
TeamList <- list()

for (i in 1:length(teamLinks)){

  # [...] your scraping code that leads to a "df"

  TeamList[[i]] <- df

}
```

Then name the `TeamList`'s dataframes based on each team, and then convert the list of dataframes into multiple dataframes with `list2env()`:

```
names(TeamList) <- Team

list2env(TeamList, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```